# Window.print() bypass print dialog

Tags: javascript, printing

Is there a way to use window.print() and save the PDF file without having the print dialog coming up? (especially in Chrome, other browsers would be nice to have)

Comment: If I read what [window.print()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) does: "Opens the Print Dialog to print the current document.", then the answer is: NO. Also, think about it, if any website could access the printer without any user permission, what would happen?

Comment: I doubt it, at least not without an extension or altering the browser source code yourself, else it'd be a security issue

Comment: Also I think it's not guaranteed that everyone has a "print to PDF" option. Maybe it's an option for you to create the PDF on the server side.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't officially control anything outside of your own webpage on the client's browser (without a browser extension, at least), so there's no allowed way to bypass the print dialog. What you can do is use JavaScript to save the page as a PDF. However, I am unaware of any JS library that works without some modifications. For example, here's a setup that uses the JS [library jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).

```js
let doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
doc.addHTML(document.body,function() {
    doc.save('html.pdf');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<p>Test page to demonstrate functionality.</p>
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/07/24/11/59/canary-4360002_960_720.jpg" alt="Canary, Gran Canaria, Spain, Spanish, Volcanic, Island">
<img width=100 src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
```

While it does download the page as a PDF without user confirmation, only Base64 images get downloaded, not any other images from external URLs, which could be vital for your page. As a workaround, you'd have to convert all images to Base64 images. While it could work, you could run into issues depending on image format, source (cross-origin protections exist), among other characteristics. It would be tricky to set up in a way that would consistently work across your site.

Thus, the best solution would be to handle it from server side as user somega suggested. The specifics on how to do that are going to depend on your server side language (PHP, Java, Python, etc.) and specific environment, but no matter your setup there's likely some library that will handle this easier than from the front-end with JavaScript.